# Recommended way of installing two or more Python applications sharing dependencies

Tags: python

Here is the situation: I have installed applications distributed only via `pip install`. `pip install` installs application scripts (entry-points) to one of directories designated by `$PATH` and I can execute those apps from anywhere.

If two apps share a dependency, upgrading one will affect the other. Is there a recommended way to avoid such a situation?

Comment: https://pypa.github.io/pipx/ is the canonical solution.

Comment: @AKX or any other virtual environment solution

Comment: @ASK Thank you! I thought that the problem was well-known and that someone should have solved it. It's really odd 30m of googling doesn't reveal it. I'm disappointed in my poor search skills .